# Creating a binned column in PostgreSQL database

Tags: python, postgresql, bin

I am trying to convert a python script line which create binned data column (postgreSQL table column: num_subjects_enrolled). How can I modify it to postgres query.

```
num_subjects_enrolled     bin_num_subjects_enrolled_int
583                       500 <x ≤ 1000
```

```
BinBySpecificLimits(Integer([num_subjects_enrolled]),0,30,200,500,1000,Max(Integer([num_subjects_enrolled])))
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Use `case` to bin your values.